# Server dosen't reconognize mondodb module whit angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, server, forever

I'm trying run a server configuration whit this instruccion.

> forever start --uid "mns_server_dev_7200" index.js.

but I can't, I have this error

> module.js:549
>       throw err;
>              ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Object. (/mns_server/index.js:12:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3) error: Forever detected  script exited with code: 1

but in my npm list I have installed the module 'mongoose'
[part of modules list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuR3m.png)

so, I have been readding about this bug but I couldn't resolve it

Comment: Can you share your file structure? It would be helpful to know where is the index.js, package.json and node_modules folder

Comment: sure, the directories tree is
/mns_server/index.js
/mns_server/node_modules/*
/mns_server/package.json